# Is there a way to view monsters' status?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

In Knights of Pen and Paper there are a number of status effects you can inflict on enemies, such as weakness, bleeding, setting them on fire, etc. Most of these have a handy icon displayed on the monster themselves, but these can be hard to see due to the (charming) pixelly graphics. This is especially true when there are more than 3-4 enemies on the screen. In addition to this, monsters can be hit by the same effect multiple times (e.g. Warrior's Strike and Cleric's Weakening) but I can't tell if they stack or not as the icon doesn't change.

**Is there a way to see the current status effects on the monsters and players during battle?** This would be invaluable for the harder battles where you need to strategise a bit more. I've tried clicking on the monster but it just does a default attack (which is near useless for magic wielders) and holding a finger down on them, which doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. Everything does get a little crazy and the pixilated images above the monsters don't really help. There is no way to see a list of all the effects a monster currently has.

Comment: I can't find an official source but this is what I've found as well. Ah well.